# c(++) union Data structure

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, struct, unions

I'm programming for a µC, i have following data Structure:

```
typedef struct
{
  RF12Head head;

  typedef union 
  {
    uint8_t raw[40];

    typedef struct
    {
      node_id nodeId;
      uint8_t hierachyDepth;
    } MessageNodeFound;
  } data;

} RF12Message;
```

A RF12Message contains a header an an data part.
Now i want to have different message formats.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
RF12Message msg;

memset(&msg.data.raw, 0xEF, sizeof(msg.data.raw)); // fill in directly

//or indirectly:

msg.data.MessageNodeFound.nodeId = 3;
msg.data.MessageNodeFound.hierachyDepth = 2;
```

but the compiler aways throws an error: "invalid use of 'RF12Message::data'", why?

thank you!

Comment: data is a typedef of the union, not a variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many `typedef`s in your code.
Try this:

http://codepad.org/frysgQte

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your `typedef` statements. RF12Message::data is *not* a `union` of 40 `uint8_t`s and a `MessageNodeFound`; it is a datatype consisting of those things.

A similar problem will affect your declaration of `MessageNodeFound`. Remove both `typedef`s, and I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For C++

The typedef declarations just declare a type. There is no data member called 'MessageNodeFound' or 'data' also for that matter.

This should give you an idea

```
typedef struct 
{ 

   typedef union  
   { 
      char raw[40]; 

      typedef struct 
      { 
         int nodeId; 
         char hierachyDepth; 
      } MessageNodeFound;

      MessageNodeFound m;

   } Data; 
   Data d;
} RF12Message;

int main(){
   RF12Message msg; 

   memset(&msg.d.raw, 0xEF, sizeof(msg.d.raw)); // fill in directly 

   //or indirectly: 

   msg.d.m.nodeId = 3; 
   msg.d.m.hierachyDepth = 2;
}
```